# Split a dataframe into smaller dataframes in R using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `dataframe` with `118` observations and has three columns in total. Now, I would like to split this dataframe into `two` `dataframes` with `59` observations each. I tried two different approaches but none of them returned what I wanted.

How can I do this using `dplyr` in `R`?

Sample dataframe:

```
Code Count_2020 Count_2021
A    1          2
B    2          4
C    3          6
D    4          8
E    5          10
F    6          12
```

Desired output:

DF1

```
Code Count_2020 Count_2021
    A    1          2
    B    2          4
    C    3          6
```

DF2

```
Code Count_2020 Count_2021
    D    4          8
    E    5          10
    F    6          12
```

1st Approach

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775239/emulate-split-with-dplyr-group-by-return-a-list-of-data-frames)

```
library(tidyverse)
df= df %>% group_split(Code)
```

Now this returns a list of `118`, so it's a list of `118` observations where each `list` has `3` columns.

2nd Approach

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57107721/how-to-name-the-list-of-the-group-split-output-in-dplyr)

```
library(tidyverse)
df= df %>% sample_n(size = 59) %>% 
  split(f = as.factor(.$Code))
```

Now this returns a list of `59`.

Comment: What's the logic you're trying to use? You have 118 different codes, so when you split by that, you get 118 data frames...what did you expect instead? Your code only knows the logic you give it, so if you want to lump codes together, or you want to split to have a certain number of rows or a certain ratio of the total rows in each, you have to put that in your code

Comment: I see, that's why I switched to the second approach

Comment: So are you trying to find a way to do this without hard-coding the number of rows per group?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We may use `gl` to create the grouping column in `group_split`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
      group_split(grp = as.integer(gl(n(), 59, n())), .keep = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

We could use `slice`

```
library(dplyr)

DF1 <- DF %>% 
    slice(1:3)

DF2 <- DF %>% 
    slice(4:6)
```

Output:

```
> DF1
  Code Count_2020 Count_2021
1    A          1          2
2    B          2          4
3    C          3          6
> DF2
  Code Count_2020 Count_2021
1    D          4          8
2    E          5         10
3    F          6         12
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `split` -

```
n <- 3
split(df, ceiling(seq(nrow(df))/n))

#$`1`
#  Code Count_2020 Count_2021
#1    A          1          2
#2    B          2          4
#3    C          3          6

#$`2`
#  Code Count_2020 Count_2021
#4    D          4          8
#5    E          5         10
#6    F          6         12
```